# How do i search Organizations by type in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure, smart-on-fhir

How do i search Organizations by Organization types e.g prov,dep,gov on FHIR server.
i want to display only prov Organizations from a list of orgnizations that contains prov,gov,dep.

Tried this "GET [base]/Organization?type=prov" and did not return any results.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good, so possibly:

- the server does not have any Organizations with the type code being 'prov'
- the server does not support the 'type' search parameter

In the first case you would get an empty Bundle - no results, which is not an error(!). In the second case you could get an OperationOutcome detailing why the search failed.

Comment: Also, best practice is to specify the code system along with the code as, in theory, there can be codes from different code systems with the same code value and different meaning.

Comment: for the second case you can check by getting the server's capability statement